# How to store a position in an array and use for later in c++?

Tags: c++

I have an array that displays like this:

[image]

I want the items in the array to be saved to be replaced later. (the "@" symbol is the player)

The controls work by replacing the players current position with a `'.'` and replacing the next `'.'` with the `'@'` symbol according to which direction the player is moving. Here's the code for this:

```cpp
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) {
                int y2 = y + 1;
                int temp = cMap[y2][x];

                if (cMap[y2][x] != '#') {
                    cMap[y][x] = cMap[y2][x];
                    y++;
                    cMap[y][x] = '@';
                }
            }
```

Elaboration: I want the `E` on the array to be saved, so after the player moves from being in its place, it will be replaced instead of being turned to a `'.'`.

Here's the issue in action:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl0ZA.jpg

Here's the full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char cMap[20][35] = {
    "##################################",
    "#@...............................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "#................................#",
    "##########.#.....................#",
    "#..........#.....................#",
    "#..........#.....................#",
    "#....E.....#.....................#",
    "#..........#.....................#",
    "#..........#.....................#",
    "#..........#.....................#",
    "##################################"
};

// y = 14; x = 29

bool running = true;

int x = 1, y = 1;

int main() {

    // Game loop
    while (running) {
        system("cls");

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            cout << cMap[i] << endl;
        }

        system("pause>nul");

        // controls
        if (running) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) {
                int y2 = y + 1;

                if (cMap[y2][x] != '#') {
                    cMap[y][x] = '.';
                    y++;
                    cMap[y][x] = '@';
                }
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)) {
                int y2 = y - 1;

                if (cMap[y2][x] != '#') {
                    cMap[y][x] = '.';
                    y--;
                    cMap[y][x] = '@';
                }
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)) {
                int x2 = x + 1;

                if (cMap[y][x2] != '#') {
                    cMap[y][x] = '.';
                    x++;
                    cMap[y][x] = '@';
                }
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) {
                int x2 = x - 1;

                if (cMap[y][x2] != '#') {
                    cMap[y][x] = '.';
                    x--;
                    cMap[y][x] = '@';
                }
            }

            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
    system("cls");

    cout << "Player closed the game." << endl;

    system("pause>nul");

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This isn't really a question people can answer because we don't know anything about your code. The only thing anyone can say, which is pretty straight-forward, is that you need to save its position somehow. Have you considered keeping a list of coordinates for items you want to display, and always displaying it if `@`'s coordinates are not over `E`?

Comment: @Human-Compiler sorry about that, just fixed it.

Comment: Given the code sample I think caching the index variables or using a pointer are equally viable, but the index variables strike me as more useful overall. As an added bonus it looks like you're already storing them.

Comment: Side note: `system("cls");` is pretty ugly. You're using windows key primitives, so consider digging around in the [windows API for direct console control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/) so you can update single characters on the screen rathe than redrawing the whole screen and getting flicker. I know there are [Curses libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) for Windows that'll do this, but there has to be a function you can call directly.

Comment: What does "Can anyone help" mean? What is your specific question about C++, the programming language? "How to store a position in an array and use for later in c++?" This question answers itself: you store your current position in some other variable or object, and use it whenever you want to. It is not clear what your answerable question is. In general, ["Can anyone help me" is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), and is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already store the position of the player in `x` and `y`, so you know how to do this. The position of `E` is constant, so you can reflect that by using `const int` variables. Before your loop:

```
int main()
{
    const int e_x = 5; // Please note I haven't counted this, I leave that to you
    const int e_y = 15; // These should be the exact positions in your array
```

Then in your loop, you simply assign `'E'` to the element `cMap[e_x][e_y]`. And then you assign `'@'` to the element `cMap[x][y]`. This will overwrite the `'E'` if they are the same, but at the next iteration of the loop the `'E'` will be restored.

```
    while(running) {
        cMap[e_x][e_y] = 'E';
        cMap[x][y] = '@';
        // cout your characters
        // do the key checking
```

You can restore the `'.'` in the same way, if you just store the previous x and y before updating it when the keys are pressed. This will make your code much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks so much man. That is exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replacing a character in your `cMap` (and storing its previous content), you could simply update two cells on each move: the previous `(x, y)` position (just use `cMap`) and the new one (place an `@` there).

NOTE: more than one key can be down at the same time.

You should avoid repeating the same code (four times!). First, figure out the new coordinates you should move to (`x2`, `y2`), then do ONE check and ONE update. (I assume you'd take user4581301's suggestion about using console API).